# My Discord test bot returns 'That member was not found' even though the member is in my server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm watching a video tutorial on YouTube on how to make a Discord bot. I believe I kinda understand what I'm doing at this point. But I just have no idea why it returns that. I did as the video said and everything was working until that point where I was testing kicking members from the server.

Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const {Client} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const PREFIX = "y!";


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    console.log(`[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`);
    if (message.content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('konnichiwa');
        message.channel.send('mata konnichiwa');
        message.channel.send('konnichiwa');
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
            .trim()
            .substring(PREFIX.length)
            .split(/\s+/);
        console.log(CMD_NAME);
        console.log(args); 

        if (CMD_NAME === 'kick') {
            if (!message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) 
                return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
            if (args.length === 0) 
                return message.reply('Please provide an ID.');
            const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
            if (member) {
                member.kick().then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} was kicked`)).catch((err) => message.channel.send('I do not have permissions...'));
            }   else {
                message.channel.send('That member was not found...');
            }

            
        }
        else if (CMD_NAME === 'ban') {
            if (!message.member.permissions.has('BAN_MEMBERS'))
                return message.reply('You do not have permission to use that command');
            if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Please provide an ID.');
            message.guild.members.ban(args[0]);
        }
    }
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Do you have any error or anything that could help us discover where is the problem? Also does only the kick command not work or all the commands that have a prefix, or maybe the bot doesn't respond to anything no matter what people type?

Comment: Do you have Guild Members intent?

Comment: @MalikLahlou when i try to put (!) on the line ```if (member) {``` the error becomes typerror and 'kick' isn't recognized. I thought putting ! might help since it wouldn't return the message if it was true. I'm actually not sure.

Comment: @MrMythical I'm not sure if I have one. I think the tutorial I'm watching may be outdated. He didn't need to put any intent. I was getting the error and search for solutions on google. and I just put "GUILDS" "GUILD_MESSAGES". I'm not sure if that is enough. I will try searching for guild members intent

Comment: @MrMythical I tried adding the "GUILD_MEMBERS" intent but it still returns 'That members was not found'. There are no errors.

Comment: hello @MrMythical upon searching guild members intent, I also found guild presences intent. It seems that that was what missing in my code. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you define args? I would try doing args[1] or at least have it console.log(args[0]) to see that it’s getting the right name

Comment: @QuazArxx I'm not sure because I'm a newbie but I think it's at the ```if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        const [CMD_NAME, ...args] = message.content
            .trim()
            .substring(PREFIX.length)
            .split(/\s+/);
        console.log(CMD_NAME);
        console.log(args); ```